# PNG tiles in OSMDroid

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I've got an app that uses osmdroid 4.3. The tile source I use is Mapnik. Current extension `.png.tile`. How can I modify my tile source to save tiles is `.png`? This is how I do:

```
new XYTileSource("Mapnik", ResourceProxy.string.offline_mode,
                minZoom,
                maxZoom, 256,
                ".png", new String[] {});
```

But it's still `png.tile`.

Comment: the real question is, why do you need them as .png?

Answer (score 0):

".tile" is added by osmdroid on purpose: it avoids filling Gallery apps with hundreds of cached tiles.

If you absolutely need to change that, you will have to change and recompile osmdroid.

Comment: Sometimes IllegalArgumentException(code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=505) occurs. >Throwing and IllegalArgumentException when the bitmap is not equal sized or not in JPG/PNG format - is a documented behavior. So I guess changing extesion from png.tile to png would help

Comment: You can raise again this issue about IllegalArgumentException in osmdroid GitHub project issues. But changing tiles extension will certainly not fix it.